# Issues pulling host names and Os versions - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Quick question here, I need to pull the Os version 200+ servers.. I found the way to do that via

```
$servers = get-content "C:\Automation\Servers.txt"
Get-WmiObject -class win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $servers | Select-Object Caption
```

However the results kicked back are as such

```
Caption                                                                                                                                      
-------                                                                                                                                      
Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003, Standard Edition                                                                                        
Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003, Enterprise Edition                                                                                      
Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003, Enterprise Edition                                                                                      
Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003, Enterprise Edition                                                                                      
Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003, Enterprise Edition                                                                                      
Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003, Enterprise Edition                                                                                      
Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003, Enterprise Edition                                                                                      
Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003 Enterprise x64 Edition                                                                                   
Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003, Enterprise Edition                                                                                      
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard                                                                                                    
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter                                                                                                  
Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003, Enterprise Edition                                                                                      
Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003, Enterprise Edition                                                                                      
Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003 Standard x64 Edition                                                                                     
Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003, Standard Edition
```

Now the main issue is some failed so I cant just count down the list and put a name on them... Is there a way to get the program to write the host name from my file next to the version? Or am I barking up the wrong tree....

I did find a way to do it with Ip addresses as such

```
$servers = get-content "C:\Automation\Servers.txt"
foreach ($server in $servers) {
  $addresses = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server)
  foreach($a in $addresses) {
    "{0},{1}" -f $server, $a.IPAddressToString
  }
```

However this is not using WMI objects its using "System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server)" so im not sure how to adapt this to my needs, any help would be great. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have misread your post but if you are trying to match the hostname with os version you could do the following:

```
get-content "C:\Automation\Servers.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    $caption = Get-WmiObject -class win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $_ | Select-Object Caption
    "{0},{1}" -f $_,$caption
}
```

I think you could make it smaller but i find it easier to read like this.

Comment: PERFECT!!! This is just what i needed... Now how does this work? I really dont understand what the ""{0},{1}"" does? Is this type of action called something so I can google and learn about it?

Comment: It's creating a formatted string. you could have
    `"My name is {1} and my favorite colour is {0}" -f "blue","Matt"`
Matt will assume position 1 in the string and blue will assume position 0 creating
`"My name is Matt and my favorite colour is blue" `
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/03/11/understanding-powershell-and-basic-string-formatting.aspx
The link contains a more in depth look at the -f operator which can do more.

Answer (score 1):

The Win32_operatingsystem objects you are obtaining already have a PSComputerName property, so you just need to select it :

```
$servers = get-content "C:\Automation\Servers.txt"
Get-WmiObject -class win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $servers | Select-Object PSComputerName,Caption
```

Or , if you don't like the name "PSComputerName", you can change the name of this property :

```
$servers = get-content "C:\Automation\Servers.txt"
Get-WmiObject -class win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $servers | Select-Object @{Name="Hostname";Expression={$_.PSComputerName }},Caption
```

That's it.